# Silverlight BusyIndicator Content disabling

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, prism, busyindicator, regionadapter

I'm using the busy indicator from the Silverlight toolkit. I'm binding the IsBusy property to a property in my viewmodel to disable the content and have it display the BusyIndicator. I'm also using Prism's RegionManager's TabControlRegionAdapter to inject views into a tabcontrol.

Ordinarily this works fine, but I noticed an odd bug. The scenario is I disable content for one view, switch to a different tab, throw an event using the eventAggregator that sets the first view's IsBusy to false in it's viewModel, and then switch back to the first tab. If I do this, the BusyIndicator is gone, but the content is still disabled.

Thoughts?

Comment: where you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Canvas.ZIndex` property of the BusyIndicator.  I've set mine to 1 and that seems to solve these type of issues granted I am using the RadBusyIndicator, but the same principles may be at play.